# Interpolation of 2D scattered non-uniform data numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a data file which looks like this:

```
1.0  2.1  2.4  3.0  3.1  3.2  3.7  3.9  4.2

1.3  1.6  1.8  1.9  2.8  2.9  3.7  3.9  4.0  4.4  4.7  4.9 

1.4  0.4  0.5  1.5  1.8  2.2  2.5  2.8  2.9  3.6

1.8  1.1  1.3  1.9  2.1  2.8  3.7  3.9  4.0  4.2  4.7  4.9  5.2  5.8

2.1  0.2  0.3  1.1  1.4  1.6  1.9
```

Here the first column corresponds to the x-values (not uniformly spaced) and for each x value the rest of the data in that row are y-values. I know the number of y-values in each row. The original data file has 200 such rows. For each of these xs and ys I have z(x,y). Now I want to make a 2D interpolation to a new grid as below:

```
1.1  1.0  2.2  2.4

1.3  1.1  1.3  2.0  2.2

1.7  1.2  1.5  2.0  2.4

1.9  1.4  1.5  1.8  2.0  2.2  2.4
(40 such rows)
```

and so on. Here as before the first column is x (xnew) values and all the remaining element in the row are the y (ynew) values, none of which are uniformly spaced. I have to find znew(xnew,ynew).

I have tried the following things with `R` `z` and `alpha` as `x` `y` and `z` respectively:

1. Set `z` as a 2D array and set all the missing values as `nan`. Use `interpolate.interp2d`. It's saying,

   ```
   No more knots can be added because the number of B-spline coefficients
       already exceeds the number of data points m. Probably causes: either
       s or m too small. (fp>s)
       kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=128,129 m=16000 fp=nan s=0.000000
   and znew has only 0 or nan as values.
   ```
2. `f1=interpolate.griddata(R,z,alpha,method='linear')`

   ```
   QH6154 qhull precision error: initial facet 1 is coplanar with the interior
   point
   ERRONEOUS FACET:
   ```
3. `f1=interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(R,z,alpha)`
   its giving an error.

What is the best way of performing 2D interpolation on this data?

Comment: Rather than showing us how your data files are organised, it would be much more useful if you showed samples of your actual `R`, `z` and `alpha` variables.

Answer (score 1):

[`RectBivariateSpline` is for uniform grids only](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html), so you can't use that.

Otherwise, it sounds like you're probably just feeding in the data incorrectly -- but we can't tell, because you haven't shown us the critical part of your code.  For an irregular grid, the `x, y, z` input to `interp2d` should have the same numbers of points.  Is that true for your inputs?  (Just before you call `interp2d`, print `x.size`, etc.)  If this doesn't show you what you've done wrong, edit your question to show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `griddata` is incorrect. The syntax is [`griddata(points, values, xi, ...)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), where:

> **`points`**:
>   ndarray of floats, shape (n, D) Data point coordinates. Can
>   either be an array of shape (n, D), or a tuple of ndim arrays.
>
> **`values`**:
>   ndarray of float or complex, shape (n,) Data values.
>
> **`xi`**:
>   ndarray of float, shape (M, D) Points at which to interpolate
>   data.

If I understand your description correctly, the function you are trying to interpolate has the form `alpha = f(R, z)`, such that `R` and `z` specify the coordinates at which your `alpha` values were sampled. `R`, `z`, and `alpha` should all be 1D vectors of the same length. If this interpretation is correct, then

- The `values` parameter should be `alpha`
- `points` should be an `(n, 2)` array consisting of your `R` and `z` vectors concatenated together.
- You also need to specify `xi`, which correspond to the points at which to evaluate the interpolant (i.e. your "xnew, ynew" values). This is *not* the same thing as `alpha`!

---

As @Mike mentioned, `RectBivariateSpline` is for regular grids only (as is `interp2d`), and you certainly can't get around this constraint by just filling in the missing values with NaNs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. You are right that my problem has the form alpha=f(R,z). But the set of z values for each R is different. So I am not sure how would I put z and alpha as 1D array? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the set of z values for each R". For the interpolation to make sense, each value in `alpha` must be associated with a single value in `R` and a single value in `z`. Perhaps your `R` and `z` values are on some sort of grid after all? As I said, it's hard to understand what's going on without seeing what your actual `R`, `z` and `alpha` arrays look like.

Comment: Hmm.  The [`interp2d` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) suggests that it is capable of dealing with irregular grids.  And I get reasonable results.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yjrrhjqtg6awjc/disk2d.z?dl=0
This is the file for z grids. The first column is R values and the second column is the integer specifying the number of z values present for that particular R.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fda6rwfxm1x3vww/disk2d.alpha?dl=0
The file for alpha in the same fashion. First column is R and second column is number of alpha values for each R, same as z.